# QList takeLast() and removeLast() conflict

Tags: c++, qt

When I try to run this code:

```
QStringList foo;
foo << "bar";
QString last;
last = foo.takeLast();
qDebug() << last;
foo.removeLast();
```

The IDE raises this error:

> ASSERT: “!isEmpty()” in file ......\Qt\Qt5.3.0\5.3\mingw482_32\include/QtCore/qlist.h, line 299

If I disable the line with `removeLast()` command by toggling comment the code works fine.
I do not understand this behavior since `takeLast()` runs when `foo` is not yet an empty list (`removeLast()`  is called successively).
Is a bug? is there a way to save the last before `QStringList` is emptied?

Answer (score 3):

It's a quite common convention in such APIs, that the word "take" is ought to be taken literally - this function really *takes* away the last element, i.e. removes it, and returns it. You can read about it in [the documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlist.html#takeLast):

> Removes the last item in the list and returns it.

You can use [`last()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlist.html#last) to obtain the last element without removing it. This is also Qt's prevailing convention that *getters* are named without the word "get" - just the name of the thing they're "getting".

Comment: Hi @user3713179 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 3):

`QList::takeLast()` removes the last element from the list, as explain in the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlist.html#takeLast).

**Use `QList::last()` instead (or, equivalently, `QList::back()`).**